# Mongodb $addFields, return field value from function?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am storing in my mongodb collection the video id of a video served in the cloud. When my front end makes an API call for that video, I want to return the formatted URL based on that video id. I have a function that does this, but I can't get it to work with `$addFields` in and `aggregate` pipeline:

My documents look like this:

```
{
    "date" : ISODate("2018-03-30T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "title" : "Tips and Tricks", 
    "video_id" : "13966740", 
}
```

...and I want my API call to return them with an extra field, `"image_url"`:

```
{
    "date" : ISODate("2018-03-30T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "title" : "Tips and Tricks", 
    "video_id" : "13966740", 
    "image_url" : "https://myhostingservice.com/13966740/preview_image", 
}
```

This is what I'm trying in models/video.js:

```
const hostingservice = require('myhostingservicehelperfunctions');

module.exports.getVideo = function (callback) {
    videoCollection.aggregate(
        [
            { $match: { } },
            { $addFields: {
                    image_url: hostingservice.createImageURL("$video_id")
                }
            },
            { $sort: {
                'date' : -1 }
            }
        ],
        callback);
};
```

The helper function simply takes the string param and  returns a string.

`myhostingservicehelperfunctions.js`:

```
module.exports.createImageURL = function ImageURL(video_id){
    return 'https://myhostingservice.com/' + video_id + '/preview_image';
};
```

My front end receives all the correct data, but the value of `image_url` is "`https://myhostingservice.com/$video_id/preview_image`", which makes me think my function ran, but it was passed the actual string `"$video_id"`, not the value of the key, `video_id`. Look closely, the URL contains `"$video_id"`, not `"13966740"` from the example above.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you show the "createImageURL" function as well

Comment: I have added it above. The function simply returns a concatenated string based on the string passed in. It is doing that, but the string it was passed is "$video_id" instead of "13966740", which I was expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't concatenate strings like that in mongoDB aggregation, you'll need to concatenate strings using the concat operator, so the function "createImageURL" should look something like this,

```
module.exports.createImageURL = function ImageURL(){
    return { $concat: [ "https://myhostingservice.com/", "$video_id", "/preview_image" ] };
};
```

Comment: That function takes no argument, so how will $video_id contain a value?

Comment: you don't need an argument, you don't need to pass the value of video_id, you just need to pass the key name and the concat operation will automatically append the value of that key name. The only requirement here is that in that stage of the pipeline the key name should be video_id

Comment: WOW! I did not expect that to work, but it did! It looks like the key name $video_id is still in scope in the $concat operation. I didn't realize that was possible.

Comment: mongodb 4.4 support: $addFields: { $function: ... }